# node encode and decode utf-16 buffer

Tags: javascript, node.js

im working on a javascript/nodejs application that needs to talk with a C++ tcp/udp socket. It seems like I get from the old C++ clients an utf16 buffer. I didn't found a solution right now to convert it to a readable string and the other direction seems to be the same problem.

Is there a easy way for this two directions?

Nice greetings

Answer (score 15):

If you have a UTF-16-encoded buffer, you can convert it to a <s>UTF-8</s> Javascript string like this:

```
let string = buffer.toString('utf16le');
```

To read these from a stream, it's easiest to use convert to string at the very end:

```
let chunks = [];
stream.on('data', chunk => chunks.push(chunk))
      .on('end',  ()    => {
        let buffer = Buffer.concat(chunks);
        let string = buffer.toString('utf16le');
        ...
      });
```

To convert a JS string to UTF-16:

```
let buffer = Buffer.from(string, 'utf16le')
```

Comment: `.toString('utf16le');` is particulary useful when sending accent letters through GSM SMS messages

Comment: Javascript strings are **NOT** in UTF-8.

Comment: @КонстантинВан you're right, see my edit.