# node js base64 string into utf8 issue

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a string which is base64 and I need to convert it into utf-8.

```
base64_string "VABpAG0AZQAgAHMAZQByAGUAaQBzAA=="
```

I am trying to convert base64_string into utf-8 in the following env:

In browser

```
method : atob(base64_string)

`Result = "Time series",`
```

which is correct. We can verify the same in `https://www.base64decode.org`

In NodeJs I am converting with npm package "atob"

```
method : atob(base64_string)

Result = "T i m e  s e r i e s".
```

For some reasons, I am getting spaces between each character and I don't know why?
I have tried to trim, but that is also not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR;**

Your string is actually UTF-16, not UTF-8. Here's how to decode it properly.

```
function atob(b64txt) {
  const buff = Buffer.from(b64txt, 'base64');
  const txt = buff.toString('utf16le');
  return txt;
}
```

**Explanation:** Your base64 encoded string isn't actually UTF-8 or ASCII data. It's UTF-16 (little-endian). That means every character **always** has two bytes.

UTF-8 is different: any byte that is less than 127 indicates a single-byte character. A byte greater than 127 would have a second byte, and if the second byte is > 127 there would be a third byte, etc.

So let's decode your string to character codes and see what it looks like:

```
const b64txt = 'VABpAG0AZQAgAHMAZQByAGUAaQBzAA==';
const buff = Buffer.from(b64txt, 'base64');
console.log(JSON.stringify(buff));
// >> {"type":"Buffer","data":[84,0,105,0,109,0,101,0,32,0,115,0,101,0,114,0,101,0,105,0,115,0]}
```

First character (84) is the ASCII character for `T`. But it's less than 127, and it still has a `0` byte following it. So...not UTF-8.

That's the clue that this string has two bytes per character, making it UTF-16. And the fact that the 0 follows the character is the clue that it's "little-endian" (the 0-255 byte comes first, and the 256-65536 byte comes second).

If you want to change this buffer into text, you need to interpret it as the correct type of string:

```
const txt = buff.toString('utf16le'); // <- UTF-16, little-endian
console.log(txt);
// >> "Time sereis"
```

So in node.js, if you combine those two commands, you end up with a full fledged solution to get your string decoded properly, as above in the TL;DR;.

Of course if your encoding type changes, you'd have to change this as well, and do `toString('utf8')` or whatever the appropriate encoding is.

(credit: I referenced [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573001/nodejs-how-to-decode-base64-encoded-string-back-to-binary) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40418384/node-encode-and-decode-utf-16-buffer) as I was drafting this answer.)